# How can I speed up a function combining rbind and lapply?

Tags: r, lapply, rbind

I have a large dataframe(100K rows, 19 columns). I need to count the number of cases each month that contain each possible combination of 5 items.

The following code works for a small dataset but with my complete dataset it takes way too long. From my searching I suspect that pre-allocating a dataframe is the key, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

```
library(dplyr)

Case<-c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,8,8,8,9,9,9)
Month<- c("Jan","Jan","Jan","Mar","Mar","Sep","Sep","Nov","Nov","Dec","Dec","Dec","Apr","Dec","Dec","Dec","Dec","Dec","Dec")

Fruits<-c("Apple","Orange","Grape","Grape","Orange","Apple","Apple","Orange","Grape","Apple","Orange","Grape","Grape","Apple","Orange","Grape","Apple","Orange","Grape")

df<-data.frame(Case,Month,Fruits)


Patterns <- with(df, do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(Case), function(x){
  y <- subset(df, Case == x )
  Date<-as.character(y$Month[1])
  Fruits <- paste(unique(y$Fruits[order(y$Fruits)]), collapse = ' / ') 
  as.data.frame(unique (cbind(Case = y$Case, Date, Fruits)))
})))

Total<-Patterns %>%
  group_by(Date,Fruits) %>%
  tally()
```

The results I get are acceptable but the process takes too long and with a large dataset I run out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over large datasets, `data.table` will be a lot quicker than dplyr:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, toString), by = c("Case","Month")][,.N, by = c("Fruits","Month")]
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do all of it in one command using `dplyr`. First we `group_by` `Case` and `Month` to paste all `Fruits` together by group and then grouping by `Month` and `Fruits` we add the number of rows for each group using `tally`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Case, Month) %>%
   summarise(Fruits = paste(Fruits, collapse = "/")) %>%
   group_by(Month, Fruits) %>%
   tally()
   # OR count()

#  Month Fruits                 n
#  <fct> <chr>              <int>
#1 Apr   Grape                  1
#2 Dec   Apple/Orange/Grape     3
#3 Jan   Apple/Orange/Grape     1
#4 Mar   Grape/Orange           1
#5 Nov   Orange/Grape           1
#6 Sep   Apple                  2
```

Comment: I am embarrassed at how simple that was. Thank you so much.